# Draw an image in Additive Blend Mode without using OpenGL

Tags: iphone, uikit, core-graphics, quartz-graphics, sprite

I want to draw an image using an additive blend mode. But I don't want to use OpenGL.
I can't find anything to do this, maybe there's something in Quartz2D?

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Cheers,
Rich

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure there is enum CGBlendMode which you can use to specify blending operation.
use method:

```
CGContextSetBlendMode()
```

or

```
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height) blendMode:mode alpha:1];
```

more at developer site:
[link text](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CGBlendMode)